# Post request giving 400 bad request error in Karate with Json Parse error message

Tags: karate

I am trying to post a json in the Body of a request.Before that i am reading it and then updating few keys using set method in Karate framework.however the test passses but in console i can see that its showing 400 bad request error

I verified all the required parameters in comparison with Postman . The same Post request set up in postman works as expected.

```
Background:

     * json foojson = read ('foo.json')
     * set foojson.foo = 'foo1'
     * set foojson.foo4[0].foo7 = 'fooo8'  

Scenario: 
     Given url 
      And headers
      And json foo1json = foojson 
     And request foo1json
     And print request
     When method post
     Then status 200
```

Please find the Json example as below

```
{
  "foo": "",
  "fooA": "",
  "fooB": "",
  "fooFoo": [
    {
      "foo1": "foo A",
      "foo2": "foo AA",
      "foo3": "foo AAAA",
      "foo4": {
        "foo5": " ",
        "foo6": "foo AAAA",
        "foo7": "foo AAAA"
      },
      "foo8": "foo AAAA",
      "foo9": 0,
      "foo10": 0,
      "foo11": [
      ]
    }
  ],
  "fooC": "foo AAAA",
  "fooD": [
  ],
  "fooE": ""
}
```

Actual :

Scenario failed here

`scenarios:  1 | passed:  0 | failed:  1 | time: 2.2143`

but the trace shows the following:

```
 DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 2156.14

1 < 400

1 < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

1 < Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Content-Disposition,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,X-HTTP-Method-Override,

1 < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE

1 < Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600

1 < Cache-Control: no-cache

1 < Connection: keep-alive

1 < Content-Security-Policy: child-src 'self'

1 < Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

The specific error as below:

> {"timestamp":1557310988561,"traceId":"","path":"[POST] "",
>   "errors":[{"httpStatusCode":"BAD_REQUEST","code":"BAD_REQUEST",
>   "message":"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `foo` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `foo` out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"}]}

Please let me know if someone can help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I verified all the required parameters in comparison with Postman

That is a very un-helpful statement. Now, regarding this error:

> Cannot deserialize instance of foo out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException

It is very clear that the server has thrown this error, and it looks like Karate has sent JSON correctly, but you have not provided the request, so no-body can tell with the lack of information provided.

It really looks like Karate has found a bug in your server - which is the *whole point* of API testing :) So please check again.

If you still believe that there is some issue with Karate, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks for the help provided.  The json format was not right as u mentioned.

Comment: @avinash I'm facing the same issue, can you please tell me your approach to resolve this